# Does not display Map in Rstudio using Python Package - GEEMAP

Tags: python-3, rstudio, geemap

I am trying to use the GEEMAP package of Python in RStudio-1.4.1106.
After importing the packages and running the code shown below MAP is not displayed rather it displays the MAP attributes in the console:

```
Map(center = [40, -100],
  controls = (
    WidgetControl(
      options = ['position'],
      widget = HBox(
        children = (
          ToggleButton(
            value = False,
            icon = 'globe',
            layout = Layout(
              height = '28px',
              padding = '0px 0px 0px 4px',
              width = '28px'),
            tooltip = 'Search location/data'), ))),
    ZoomControl(options = ['position', 'zoom_in_text',
      'zoom_in_title', 'zoom_out_text', 'zoom_out_title'
    ]),
    ScaleControl(options = ['imperial', 'max_width', 'metric',
      'position', 'update_when_idle'
    ], position = 'bottomleft'),
    FullScreenControl(options = ['position']),
    MeasureControl(
      active_color = 'orange',
      options = ['active_color', 'capture_z_index', 'completed_color', 'popup_options', 'position',
        'primary_area_unit', 'primary_length_unit', 'secondary_area_unit', 'secondary_length_unit'
      ],
      popup_options = {
        'className': 'leaflet-measure-resultpopup',
        'autoPanPadding': [10, 10]
      },
      position = 'bottomleft', primary_length_unit = 'kilometers'),
    AttributionControl(
      options = ['position', 'prefix'], position = 'bottomright'),
    DrawControl(
      circle = {
        'shapeOptions': {
          'color': '#3388ff'
        }
      },
      marker = {
        'shapeOptions': {
          'color': '#3388ff'
        }
      },
      options = ['position'],
      polygon = {
        'shapeOptions': {}
      },
      polyline = {
        'shapeOptions': {}
      },
      rectangle = {
        'shapeOptions': {
          'color': '#3388ff'
        }
      }),
    WidgetControl(
      options = ['position'],
      position = 'topright',
      widget = VBox(
        children = (
          ToggleButton(
            value = False,
            icon = 'wrench',
            layout = Layout(
              height = '28px',
              padding = '0px 0px 0px 4px',
              width = '28px'),
            tooltip = 'Toolbar'), )))),
  crs = {
    'name': 'EPSG3857',
    'custom': False
  },
  default_style = MapStyle(), 
  dragging_style = MapStyle(cursor = 'move'),
  layers = (
    TileLayer(
      base = True,
      max_zoom = 19,
      min_zoom = 1,
      options = ['attribution', 'detect_retina', 'max_native_zoom', 'max_zoom', 'min_native_zoom', 'min_zoom', 'no_wrap', 'tile_size', 'tms']),
    TileLayer(
      attribution = 'Google',
      name = 'Google Maps',
      options = ['attribution', 'detect_retina', 'max_native_zoom', 'max_zoom',
        'min_native_zoom', 'min_zoom', 'no_wrap', 'tile_size', 'tms'
      ],
      url = 'https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}')),
  layout = Layout(height = '600px'),
  options = ['bounce_at_zoom_limits', 'box_zoom', 'center', 'close_popup_on_click', 'double_click_zoom', 'dragging', 'fullscreen', 'inertia', 'inertia_deceleration', 'inertia_max_speed', 'interpolation', 'keyboard',
    'keyboard_pan_offset', 'keyboard_zoom_offset', 'max_zoom', 'min_zoom', 'scroll_wheel_zoom', 'tap', 'tap_tolerance', 'touch_zoom', 'world_copy_jump', 'zoom', 'zoom_animation_threshold', 'zoom_delta', 'zoom_snap', 'zoom_start'
  ],
  scroll_wheel_zoom = True,
  style = MapStyle(), zoom = 4.0)
```

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import geemap
import ee
Map = geemap.Map(center=(40, -100), zoom=4)
Map
```

How can I display the map?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`geemap` is using `ipyleaflet` and `ipywidgets` - I don't *think* these are compatible with `Rstudio`. Try using `Jupyter` notebook instead, or Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying it on Jupiter notebook with python. it's displaying a black map but the options with the map show up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).